# Chinese encoding in Python

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, encoding, utf

When I output some Chinese character in Python (Pandas), it shows as below

```
\xe8\xbf\x99\xe7\xa7\x8d\xe6\x83\x85\xe5\x86\xb5\xe6\x98\xaf\xe6\xb2\xb9\xe6\xb3\xb5\xe6\x95\x85\xe9\x9a\x9c\xe7\x81\xaf\xef\xbc\x8c\xe6\xa3\x80\xe6\x9f\xa5\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xb8\x8b\xe6\xb2\xb9\xe6\xb3\xb5\xe6\x8f\x92\xe5\xa4\xb4\xe6\x98\xaf\xe5\x90\xa6\xe6\x8e\xa5\xe8\x99\x9a\xef\xbc\x8c\xe7\x84\xb6\xe5\x90\x8e\xe6\x9f\xa5\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xb8\x8b\xe6\xb2\xb9\xe6\xb3\xb5\xe5\x86\x85\xe7\xae\xa1\xe9\x81\x93\xe5\x8e\x8b\xe5\x8a\x9b\xe6\x98\xaf\xe5\x90\xa6\xe7\xac\xa6\xe5\x90\x88\xe6\xad\xa3\xe5\xb8\xb8\xe5\x80\xbc\xe3\x80\x82
```

What is the encoding format? It is not unicode as I know. Thanks!

Comment: Try putting `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your python source file to force Pytohn into UTF-8

Comment: that's hexadecimal

Comment: @Ben A coding directive only affects how the interpreter decodes the script itself, it has no effect on what the script does to external data that it reads or writes.

Comment: That looks like UTF-8 encoded Chinese to me, although I don't read Chinese. 这种情况是油泵故障灯，检查一下油泵插头是否接虚，然后查一下油泵内管道压力是否符合正常值。

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm assuming he's doing something like `print('你好')` and getting hex output. I don't have a lot of encoding problems, so I could very well be wrong

Comment: It is hexadecimal. There are tools online to convert hexadecimal to text :D

Comment: Surely those online tools want to know what the encoding is as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you are receiving is called a bytes object. In order to decode it, you need to do `output.decode('utf-8')`.

For example:

```
output = b'\xe8\xbf\x99\xe7...'
unicode_output = output.decode('utf-8')
print(unicode_output)
```

would then output non-latin characters (I cannot include it because it counts as spam).

Another way to do this in one-line would be:
`print(b'\xe8\xbf\x99\xe7...'.decode('utf-8'))`.

However, if that doesn't work, then it is probably because of the fact that your output isn't a bytes object, but is contained within a string. If that does not work, then there is another solution.

```
output = '\xe8\xbf\x99\xe7...'
exec('print(b\''+ output + '\'.decode(\'utf-8\'))')
```

That should be able to fix it. Hope you got something useful out of this. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

This is `bytes` type, containing a valid utf-8 Chinese text (as far as I can trust Google Translate).

If it's a string literal from your code, add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as the first line of your Python file.

If it's an external data, [here's how to convert it to a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string) (`str` type): `bytes_text.decode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 0):

`raw_bytes = b'\xe8\xbf\x99\xe7\xa7\x8d\xe6\x83\x85 . . .'`

with `raw_bytes` a `<class 'bytes'>` object containing your hexadecimal characters you can then call `decode` on `raw_bytes` and get a `<class 'str'>` representation of your characters.

`string_text = raw_bytes.decode("utf-8")`